# Randomly select vector with bounded norm

Tags: vectors, normed-spaces, random

I would like to select randomly an $n$-dimensional real vector $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^\top\in\Bbb{R}^n$ such that its norm is bounded by a positive real number, say $\sqrt{a}$, $a\in\Bbb{R}_+$. In other words,

> Select $\mathbf{x}\in\Bbb{R}^n$ such that $\lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert_2\leq\sqrt{a}$.

The simplest approach I have come up to is to uniformly draw each $x_i$ from $\left[-\sqrt{\frac{a}{n}}, \sqrt{\frac{a}{n}}\right]$, such that
$$
-\sqrt{\frac{a}{n}}\leq x_i \leq\sqrt{\frac{a}{n}}\iff x_i^2\leq\frac{a}{n}, \quad\quad i=1,\ldots,n.
$$
Then,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i^2\leq a \iff \lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert_2^2 \leq a
\iff \lVert\mathbf{x}\rVert_2\leq\sqrt{a}.
$$
Is there any more sophisticated way for doing so?

Comment: Generate $n$ i.i.d. gaussians and normalize them to lie on a a unit sphere (uniformly). Then scale the result by $\sqrt a nU^{n-1}$ for standard uniform $U$. You'll get a uniform distribution inside the ball of radius $\sqrt a$.

Comment: Scaling should be by $\sqrt a U^{1/n}$

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @A.S. How about the proposed approach shown in my question above?

Comment: In your approach, you are sampling from a box ($L^1$ norm) that lies inside the sphere - not from the ball itself ($L^2$ norm).

Comment: Of course, you're right! Thanks a lot. You could write an answer such that I can accept it.